# Delete a whole Node from an Xml Advertisement file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlnode

I am trying to delete a whole XmlNode which matches a certain condition

The format of my xml file is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Advertisements>
  <Ad>
    <ImageUrl>image/Hydrangeas.jpg</ImageUrl>
    <NavigateUrl>www.google.com</NavigateUrl>
    <AlternateText>nbfndbf</AlternateText>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <Impressions>1</Impressions>
  </Ad>
</Advertisements>
```

My deleting code:

```
      XElement x = 
                new XElement("Ad",
                  new XElement("ImageUrl", lblImageURL.Text),
                  new XElement("NavigateUrl", lblImageURL.Text),

                  new XElement("AlternateText", lblAlternateText.Text),
                    new XElement("ID", lblID.Text),
             new XElement("Impressions", lblfrequency.Text));



            string filepath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.ToString() + "Adrotator.xml";



            XmlDocument xD = new XmlDocument();

            xD.LoadXml(x.ToString());
            XmlNode xN = xD.FirstChild;

            xN.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xN);



            **xD.Save(filepath);**
```

I am getting an error **Invalid XML document. The document does not have a root element.**

Comment: *Where* is your exception being thrown? And why are you mixing LINQ to XML and XmlDocument? (It's not clear why you're loading a document just to ignore it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq to xml to achieve this here exmple how to remove node where value ID = 0

```
var q = (from c in doc.Descendants("Advertisements")
        from v in c.Elements("Ad")
        where (int) v.Element("ID") == 0
       select v).Remove();
```

here is another example using xpath

```
doc.XPathSelectElement("Advertisements/Ad[ID = 0]").Remove();
```

Comment: can i not match the whole collection of XElement with the one already present in my Xml File?

Comment: you can then you have to run the above query in a loop replacing the ID with each element node name in your xml

Comment: CS0815: Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable i get this error here (from c in doc.Descendants("Advertisements")

Comment: Can i avoid deleting the <Advertisements> tag as it is getting deleted as well

Answer (score 0):

You create a new XDocument (doc) with the following code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
```

Is there something in the Xml file (with a root element)? Also, you don't seem to use doc in the code, so it's at least not required.